# update all urls total key from javascript after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxform

Shopping cart contains urls with total key like

```
 Cart value is <span id="cart-status" >1805.32</span>
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li><a href='/Store/Category/Products?user=ADMIN&total=1805.32'>product1</a></li>
    <li><a href='/Store/Category/Products?user=ADMIN&total=1805.32'>product2</a></li>
    <li><a href='/Store/Category/Products?user=ADMIN&total=1805.32'>product3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

For proper caching in browser cart current value total=1805.32 is added to every url.

It contains also add to cart form whixh uses ajax and does not refresh page:

```html
    <form class='tdBorder js-addtocart-form' method="post">
     <span>
    <input type='hidden' name="product" value="CAR2" />
    <input class='amount' name="quantity" type="number" value="1" />
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class='btn btn-xs btn-success' />
    </form>
    
    
    <script>
        var request;
        $(function () {
            $(".js-addtocart-form").submit(function (event) {
                if (request) {
                    request.abort();
                }
                var $form = $(this);
                var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
                var serializedData = $form.serialize();
                request = $.post('@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Store")',
                    serializedData, function (response) {
                    $("#cart-status").text(response.Total);
                        var xx = $form[0].quantity;
                      .always(function () {
                          $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                      });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Cart value in page is updated in Store/AddToCart result using

```
$("#cart-status").text(response.Total)
```

How to update a elements total keys with response.Total in page ?

Bootstrap 3, jquery, ASP.NET MVC4 are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any information you store on a web page is unreliable, you should not trust it. I hope you are using it just for some kind of cache on web page only, if your server is also using total value coming from this link, then stop, you are doing it wrong. 
For you answer you can modify total parameter by this code:

```
function updateLink(val){
   $("link selector").each(function(i,v){
      var href = $(v).attr("href");
      if(href){
          href = href.replace(/total=[^&]+/,"total="+val);
          $(v).attr("href", href);
      }
   });
}
```

you need to modify `link selector` and give it some selector so that it can select all such links and call this method with new total value.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. total= is used for caching. If it is removed, browser shows old cart value in page since it reads it from cache. If it OK to use such caching or is there better solution ? I used a as link selector: `$("a")` is this OK ?

Comment: You can store it in cookies, and use it in all pages for rendering. But you need to store/calculate that information on server side as well, before performing any sensitive action for security reasons. Think like this: what if i change total=1 with the help of some javascript, will i be able to purchase cart items for 1 amount?

Comment: I don't think $("a") should be good idea. you might have more anchor tags on your page, if not now then might be tomorrow, you can add some class to such links